# jPages plugin and IE8 not showing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, jpage

I'm having some issues with this plugin and I'd like to know if anyone had this problem before and some tip/help how to fix.

I have a page that uses jPages jQuery plugin. http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/

All works fine in all browsers (Safari, IE9, Firefox, Chrome,..) but in IE8 only show the first item of the pagination and not show the other ones.

If I disable the plugin, IE8 show all content. If I try to paginate, only show the first item.

I'm using the default configuration of the plugin.

Anyone have this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: One thing that I notice is that the opacity is set to 1. Tried adding IE opacity CSS but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem as well in ie8/ie7. Fixed by a callback function that sets the current items to have an opacity of 1. Depending on the structure of the container (I am using a  in this example), you may have to change the jQuery line var onFocus = $("#coverflow_section li:eq(" + (i) + ")");.

```
$("div.pagination").jPages({
    containerID : "coverflow_section",
    callback    : ieFix,

});

function ieFix(pages, items)
{
    for(i = items.range.start - 1; i < items.range.end; i++)
    {               
        var onFocus = $("#coverflow_section li:eq(" + (i) + ")");
        onFocus.css({'opacity':1});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8 also seems to have problems with eq(). I have solved the problem with this callback:

```
$("div.pagination").jPages({
    containerID : "coverflow_section",
    callback    : ieFix,
});

function ieFix(pages, items)
{
    for(i = items.range.start; i <= items.range.end; i++)
    {               
        var onFocus = $("#coverflow_section li:nth-child("+i+")");
        onFocus.css({'opacity':1});
    }
}
```